# gRPC cmake installation doesn't generate targets file

Tags: c++, windows, git, cmake, grpc

I've been trying to build and install gRPC with cmake.  Building the project went relatively smoothly with ninja after some confusion related to acquiring nuget packages and updating the git submodules.

I am having trouble installing gRPC though.  After reading the cmake file I discovered that you need to manually set the `gRPC_INSTALL` cache variable to `ON` in order for cmake to generate an install target.  After doing this I can invoke the install target and the libraries and headers and cmake config files are emplaced.  But the cmake targets file is missing, and it isn't even being generated.  The config file is simple, all it does is call the targets file:

```
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/gRPCTargets.cmake)
```

But it doesn't look like the CMakeLists file in gRPC is even attempting to generate this file, unless I am missing something?  You can't even build the example cpp project in the gRPC repo with cmake because when it tries to find the gRPC package, the config file fails to find gRPCTargets.cmake.  So what is the proper way to build, install, and link to gRPC with cmake?  I am on Windows but that shouldn't matter with cmake.

Comment: I filed this as a grpc issue: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/10759. Pull requests with a fix are welcome.

Comment: Issue is solved in grpc master branch, but not in 1.4.x branch (current release is 1.4.7).
How can I build c++ helloworld example on windows?

Answer (score 1):

on OSX:
 run these command:

```
cd grpc

mkdir -p cmake/build

cd cmake/build

cmake -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DgRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER=package -DgRPC_ZLIB_PROVIDER=package -DgRPC_CARES_PROVIDER=package -DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2r -DOPENSSL_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2r/lib ../..

make install
```